# Function for simple math doesn't work what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, functions

This is what I wrote in the index file

```
<?php
echo "Please enter your first number?\n";

$first = stream_get_line(STDIN, 100, "\n");

echo "Please enter /, +, * or /?\n";

$operator = stream_get_line(STDIN, 100, "\n");

echo "Please enter your second number?\n";

$second = stream_get_line(STDIN, 100, "\n");

include_once "library/maths/mathsA.php";

echo doMathsA ($first, $operator, $second);
```

The function `doMathsA` looks like

```
<?php
function doMathsA ($first, $operator, $second){

  switch ($operator)

    {
        case '+';
            $result=$first+$second;
           break;

        case '*';
            $result=$first*$second;
            break;

        case '/';
            $result=$first/$second;
            break;

        case '-';
            $result=$first-$second;
             break;  
}}

echo "Your result is $result";
```

Comment: So to be clear, this is what I wrote in the index file
<?php

echo "Please enter your first number?\n";
$first = stream_get_line(STDIN, 100, "\n");

echo "Please enter /, +, * or /?\n"; 
$operator = stream_get_line(STDIN, 100, "\n");

echo "Please enter your second number?\n";
$second = stream_get_line(STDIN, 100, "\n");


include_once "library/maths/mathsA.php";

echo doMathsA ($first, $operator, $second);

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for switch/case is to have a colon `:` not a semi-colon `;` after case, so...

```
case '+' :
    $result=$first+$second;
    break;
```

etc,

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have tested the switch in another file and it does work with a semi-colon

Comment: Oh, ok. I've just noticed that you are not returning anything from the function, so the very last line (before the closing `}`) should be `return $result;`

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me but I already tried this and it doesn't return a result